# Related to Salesforce APEX and Platform Events

Tags: lightning-web-components, platform-event

I'm publishing a event in Salesforce Apex and subscribing in LWC Component.
I'm able to see my HTML model popping Up for Sys admin but not for other Profiles.
When I check in inspect getting below error.

> {"clientId":"9qs1c9blo6wyf4wqhl75dmx4qq93","channel":"/meta/subscribe","id":"6","subscription":"/event/MSAContract__e","error":"400::The channel you requested to subscribe to does not exist {/event/Contract__e}","successful":false}*

Please let me know what I can do.

Comment: I got the solution.
https://docs.informatica.com/integration-cloud/cloud-application-integration/current-version/salesforce-connector-guide/introduction-to-salesforce-connector/administration-of-salesforce-connector/assigning-object-permissions-to-the-salesforce-user-for-the-cust.html